# Calculate time difference between two times javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time, gettime

i've looking around how to do this and i found a lot of examples with complicated code.
Im using this:

```
var time1 = new Date();
var time1ms= time1.getTime(time1); //i get the time in ms
```

then i do this in other part of the code

```
var time2 = new Date();
var time2ms= time2.getTime(time2);
```

and finnally:

```
var difference= time2ms-time1ms;
var lapse=new Date(difference);  
label.text(lapse.getHours()+':'+lapse.getMinutes()+':'+lapse.getSeconds());
```

This works great,  except for one issue, the hours it gaves me are always +1 so i have to add to the code   **(time.getHours()-1)** otherwise it gaves me one hour more....

I think is an easier way to do it than all the other examples around... but i still dont understand why i need to add '-1' in order to have the correct lapse.

THanks!!!

Answer (score 16):

The problem is your timezone.

When you do `new Date(difference)`, you're creating a `Date` object that represent the moment exatcly `difference` milliseconds after January 1st, 1970. When you do `lapse.getHours()` your timezone is used in the computation. You cannot modify your timezone via Javascript, and cannot modify this behaviour. Not without some *heavy* Javascript tricks.

But your `difference` does *not* represent a date, but a *difference* of dates. Treat is as such, and compute the hours, minutes and seconds like this:

```
var hours = Math.floor(difference / 36e5),
    minutes = Math.floor(difference % 36e5 / 60000),
    seconds = Math.floor(difference % 60000 / 1000);
```

Alternatively, you can take your timezone into account when creating `lapse`:

```
var lapse = new Date(difference + new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 1000);
```

but I wouldn't recommend this: `Date` objects are overkill for your purposes.

Comment: What im tryin to represent it is a difference of dates, i will use your line  'var hours = Math.floor(difference / 36e5)'   since i dont have problems with the minutes and the seconds... That should work, right?      Thanks a lot!

Comment: i used Math.floor(difference / 36e5), and it works ,  just for curiosity what does it mean 36e5 ?

Comment: 36e5 is the number 3600000 - it's called "scientific notation" and equals 36*10^5

Comment: @DThought Exactly, it's the number of milliseconds in a hour. I use the scientific notation because it's shorter in this case. I use 6e4 too.

Comment: @user2314770 You're welcome. Remember to accept the answer if it helped you. And don't forget that your code may *still* have problems with the minutes if the timezone is shifted for fractions of an hour (as in India, for example). I still recommend to compute the minutes and the seconds on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in the `getTimezoneOffset()` returns a value in minutes, so if you want to use the lapse, you can correct it for the timezone difference like this:

```
lapse = new Date(difference); 
tz_correction_minutes = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() - lapse.getTimezoneOffset();
lapse.setMinutes(offset_date.getMinutes() + tz_correction_minutes);
```

now you can do:

```
label.text(lapse.getDate()-1+' days and'  +lapse.getHours()+':'+lapse.getMinutes()+':'+lapse.getSeconds());
```

to print out the time difference in human readable form